# Is it good practice to give an empty instance to a method?

Tags: c++, performance, class, methods

C++ newbie here! There is a class `Individual` which allocates a lot of memories so that we want to avoid having to copy. Let `mother` and `father` be two `Individual`s. I would like them to reproduce with the method `reproduce` to make another `Individual` called `baby`.

Intuitively, I would initialize `baby` with the default constructor, pass it in argument to `reproduce` and return the reference (although I suppose it is not necessary to return the reference). Here is a code that does that

```
class Individual
{
    public:
        void reproduce (const Individual& father, Individual& baby)
        {
          // Set all attributes of baby
        }
    private:
        // Plenty of variables
}

int main()
{
  // Do Stuff
    Individual mother(arg1,arg2,arg3);
    Individual father(arg1,arg2,arg3);
    // Do stuff
    Individual baby;
    mother.reproduce(father,baby);
}
```

Is this considered good practice?

Another way would be to initialize `baby` directly in the method `reproduce` and return a reference but I would predict that the `baby` would be destroyed at the end of the call of `reproduce` though.

```
class Individual
{
    public:
        Individual& reproduce (const Individual& father)
        {
            Individual baby;
        // Set all attributes of baby
        return baby
        }
    private:
        // Plenty of variables
}

int main()
{
  // Do Stuff
    Individual mother(arg1,arg2,arg3);
    Individual father(arg1,arg2,arg3);
    // Do stuff
    auto baby = mother.reproduce(father);
}
```

One could as well use an external function but I don't see what advantage that could represent.

Comment: Regarding the second case, it is undefined behavior to return reference to a temporary.

Comment: Why not just return a value? UB stands for undefined behavior. The thing the reference is referring to will go out of scope and not exist after control returns to the caller, so when they use it they get UB.

Comment: "we want to avoid having to copy as much as possible" -- Have you measured that this is a bottleneck?  Don't needlessly complicate your code in the name of performance unless you're certain optimizing will get you a measurable improvement.  Until then, just construct and return a temporary `baby` and return it.

Comment: I would return `baby` by value. It's a better model of reality than passing the externally created baby in. You can use a *move* constructor/assignment to make the return value cheap.

Comment: Note that returning an object by-value from a method doesn't typically require making a copy of that object, due to the return-value-optimization commonly implemented in most C++ compilers:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The member function `reproduce` should *return* the baby.**

It makes no sense to have a baby beforehand that's merely altered by the act of reproduction — this would be more akin to your parents finding the baby on the doorstep, having been deposited by a stork, then moulding the baby into their family; hopefully you know by now that this is not how it works!

Don't worry about performance; if your `Individual` class has a move constructor (or follows the rule of zero) then this is a complete non-issue. Even if not, Return Value Optimisation should take care of things anyway.

Your attempt to return a reference to a local variable has undefined behaviour, as you correctly intuited. So don't do this.

Comment: Note that this really has nothing to do with "methods", and it's impossible to define a "good practice" for such a specific design question about a specific piece of code.

Comment: Lemme guess. Mom and dad lied to me about the stork, too.

Answer (score 1):

I would give the `Individual` class a constructor that takes two `Individual` input parameters, e.g.:

```
class Individual
{
public:
    Individual(Individual const& mother, Individual const& father)
    {
        // Pass on traits.
    }
};
```

Unless, of course, `reproduction` also modifies the parents with relaxation, shame, or a sexually transmitted disease.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about following:

> Another way would be to initialize baby directly in the method
>   reproduce and return a reference but I would predict that the baby
>   would be destroyed at the end of the call of reproduce though.

So the first way is definetely better than abovementioned.

However, I would prefer (and this is just my IMHO) using the dynamic allocation. You can use your first method in case if you are **absolutely** sure, that `reproduce` method is not failable, and it would not be failable in future (that thing no one knows for sure).

Just imagine how your code will look like?

```
Individual baby;
mother.reproduce(father,baby);
if (baby.exists()) {
   // do stuff
}
```

The problem here that you are creating the *baby* even not being sure it would be created. I would prefer following, wherer you can be sure the (if you write the right code) that all the allocations will be done only if required.

```
Individual* reproduce (Individual *father)
...
Individual *baby = mother->reproduce(father);
if (baby != nullptr) {
    // do stuff
}
```

or

```
bool reproduce (Individual *father, Individual * &baby) // or **baby
...
Individual *baby = nullptr;
if (mother->reproduce(father, baby) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The second way is bit more error-prone or complex (as you should take care of *baby* passed is not existing, otherwise overwriting it could lead to memory leaks). Note: I prefer uniform code (and objects usage) so changed the mother and father to pointers, which is not the "must done" thing.

Also, this way you can even safely store the pointers babies in some internal "children" list in *mother* without copying data.

P.S. Just remember to delete the *baby* when it's not more needed.